# Spring data: How to set MongoOptions with <mongo:mongo> (Mongo Configuration) to change maxWaitQueueSize value

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

My xml config file looks like this. I want to set maxWaitQueueSize from defult value (50) to value 500. So I decided to add propertyname="connectionsPerHost" in my xml file.
But I can't find any option for this along with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">

<mongo:mongo id="mongoid" host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}" />
```

I know I can do this by adding the below code in my xml but not sure how to add it along with `<mongo:mongo id="mongoid">` tag.

```
<bean id="options" class="com.mongodb.MongoOptions">
    <property name="connectionsPerHost" value="${mongo.db.pool.size}"/>
</bean>
```

I tried this one:

```
<mongo:mongo id="mongoid" host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}">
        <mongo:options connections-per-host="500" />
    </mongo:mongo>
```

but getting exception like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Usage of 'mongo-options' is no longer supported for MongoDB Java driver version 3 and above. Please use 'mongo-client-options' and refer to chapter 'MongoDB 3.0 Support' for details.
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean.createInstance(MongoOptionsFactoryBean.java:221)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOptionsFactoryBean.createInstance(MongoOptionsFactoryBean.java:36)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 55 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from documentation.

1. Changed `spring-mongo-1.8.xsd` to `spring-mongo-1.8.xsd` in `xsi:schemaLocation`
2. Modified the code like:

   ```
   <!-- Mongo Configuration -->
   <mongo:mongo-client id="mongoid" host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}">
       <mongo:client-options/>
   </mongo:mongo-client>
   ```

This worked for me.